# Way to see crash logs for an iOS app outside of an Xcode debugging session?

Tags: ios, crash-reports

I have an app where the user needs to login before using it .

to enhance the user experience , the user needs only to login at the first time and each other time the app will not show the login screen but it will show the app [ I am using user default to store his id ] 
now I have achieved this but I ran into a bug and the app crashes when I open it after a succeeded login ..

**The problem is :**
to mimic the scenario where I open the app without the need to login , I had to stop the app [ which means there will be no debugging session ] and then reopen the app ..

**What I am asking for :**
is there a way to see what causes the bug knowing that I am not running the app in a debugging session ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: normally Xcode shows you the reason when the app is crashed.

Comment: @T_77 This is the idea , I am running the iossimulator without xcode knowing this , please read [the problem is ] part in my question

Comment: if that is the case....use hockey app!!!!

Comment: Hockey app is easy to use and it will send the crash reports whenever the app is crashed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Can you run your app on a device?** If so, you might be able to get the crash data you need from the *Devices* window, from Xcode.

Xcode -> Window -> Devices.

Select your device, then select *View Device Logs*.

Here's [Apple's page on the subject](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-devices_organizer/ViewingCrashLogsonaniOSDevice/ViewingCrashLogsonaniOSDevice.html).

**For running in the simulator**, you may be able to get the crash data you need from the *Console* (I've just tried this and seen at least one crash log from my current development).

Here is Apple's page on [Testing with the Simulator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html). From the menu on the left, check out *Viewing Crash Logs*. Extract from that page...

> To view a crash log
>
> 1. Open Console by going to Applications/Utilities/Console in the Finder.
> 2. Look for the line in Console that reads “Saved Crash Report for.”
> 3. Expand this item using the arrow at the left.
> 4. Click Open Report.

Comment: I wasn't sure that was the case? I thought the OP noted that the debugging session had ended... but the crash logs available via the *Devices* window are available after the app/session has died... OP noted in comments that he's using the simulator, which is why I preceded my suggestion with *Can you run your app on a device?*...

Comment: He want to test the apps in simulator . As the simulator can be run without Xcode .

Comment: OK. @iShaalan - I've updated my answer to include some information about testing with the simulator, including access to *viewing crash logs*.

Answer (score 2):

You can maybe check: https://try.crashlytics.com/

It's part of the twitter Fabric framework now quite easy to use, and provides good information

Comment: + 1 for Fabric's Crashlytics framework. The setup of the framework and tools, although quite easy, might appear a little heavy-weight and intrusive, but it is FREE, pull up ALL crash reports (contrary to Apple iTunes Connect), groups related crashlogs together, and automatically increase the 'level' of more frequent crashes, giving you a clear view of debugging priorities.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Use Hockey app for getting the info regarding the crash logs:

Here is the link to setup the Hockey app in iOS:

```
http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x/hockeyapp-for-ios
```

Answer (score 0):

check plcrashreporter : https://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/downloads/list
http://plcrashreporter.googlecode.com/svn/tags/plcrashreporter-1.1-beta1/Documentation/API/functions.html

it's very easy to use and 
If your application crashes, a crash report will be written. When the application is next run, you may check for a pending crash report, and submit the report to your own HTTP server, send an e-mail, or even introspect the report locally